# How to monitor JVM memory in Apache NiFi

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, apache-nifi, health-monitoring

I am creating a memory monitoring reporting tasks in Apache NiFi, to monitory the JVM usage. But i don't know which memory pool is appropriate to monitor usage of JVM. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Memory pools available:

- Code Cache
- Metaspace
- Compressed Class Space
- G1 Eden Space
- G1 Survivor Space
- G1 Old Gen

As per my knowledge G1 Eden Space, G1 Survivor Space and G1 Old Gen are younger generation memory pool, so these three used to monitor java heap space. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by *"complete usage of JVM"*?

Comment: Instead of individually monitoring the separate memory pool, i need to monitor the complete JVM memory.

Comment: What is *"complete JVM memory"*? Amount of reserved or committed virtual memory of a Java process? Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186322/find-my-application-memory-foot-print-programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MonitorMemory` to monitor Java Heap.
Detail is here:

[NIFI : Monitoring processor and nifi Service](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/69004/nifi-monitoring-processor-and-nifi-service.html)

[Monitor Apache NiFi with Apache NiFi](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/92495/monitor-apache-nifi-with-apache-nifi.html)